# Cross validation with two data sets

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, error

I have data gathered in two different ways and I'd like to see if a model trained with data gathered with method 1 can accurately predict data gathered with method 2. In order to get a baseline accuracy of the model I would use k-fold cross validation on the method 1 data to get a prediction error. I'm not sure how to get a comparable accuracy of the same model when predicting method 2 data however. I could train on all of method 1 data and predict the held out method 2 data and compare that error to the distribution of k errors from k-fold cross validation on method 1 data, but that seems to me like I'm comparing validation error to test error and the test error will almost always be higher.

Is there a standard way to do this? Would something like bootstrapping a distribution of changes in model error when predicting a subsample of method 1 data vs a subsample of method 2 data be better?